# Soap UI Pro Assertion using script method

Tags: soapui

Is there any way in SoapUI that I can validate the data in table after executing some process, using assertion? As part of my testing, After I execute one test step in SoapUI, I need to validate whether the table has been updated with the entry or not, using assertion.

Answer (score 0):

Using a Groovy Script test step?

Then you can use the assert command. It takes a singe parameter, that should return a boolean value.

```
assert ( true != false )
```